# How to achieve denormalizing data in impala

Tags: hive, impala

How can we achieve this to transform data in below format in Impala.

**Table**

Key | code |  actionable |  non-actionable

abcd | A | 1 | 3

abcd | A | 2 | 3

abcd | B1 | 0 | 1

abcd | B2 | 5 | 4

abcd | C1 | 0 | 0

abcd | C2 | 1 | 8

ab12 | A | 0 | 7

ab12 | B1 | 1 | 1

ab12 | B2 | 52 | 23

ab12 | C1 | 555 | 777

**deNormalized table:**

Key | a_actionable | b1_actionable | b2_actionable | c1_actionable | c2_actionable | a_non-actionable | b1_non-actionable | b2_non-actionable | c1_non-actionable

abcd | 3 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 1 | 4 | 0 | 8

ab12 | 0 | 1 | 52 | 555 | NULL

Comment: IMHO that's not normalization -- rather aggregation +  **de** normalization...

Comment: not sure how you want to denormilize the data for the first 2 rows.

Comment: I used collect_list function and concat_ws to get the denormalized output, but facing problems with huge dataset containing 1 million records.